# Is there any way to find out what programs are trying to connect to Internet on windows?

Tags: windows-vista, networking, command-line, network-monitoring

I am just wondering if it is possible to find what programmes are attempting to connect to the Internet. Is there any DOS command to do this or Is there any other programme available or will have to download a programme?

I have got Windows Vista. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the command prompt and run [netstat](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true). Just open the command line, and type

> netstat -ban

It will display every connection with the associated process.

You may also use a program called [tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437). Just run the executable and it will show you all of the current connections being made by your system.

You will need to be an **administrator** in order to see all of the connections being made but if you are infected with something serious or a rootkit, the connections may also be hidden. If you really wanted a fool proof way, you would need to setup a gateway or proxy of some sort for the machine.

Comment: If the OP has a router of some kind for his or her internet connection, it may have a connection monitor too.

Comment: +1 for tcpview - it's hella easier than trying to read netstat, but it's better than simply checking resource monitor because you can see where the connections are going (some of them might be to localhost!).

Comment: Process Explorer is a great tool too.

Answer (score 3):

Wireshark - http://www.wireshark.org/ - if you want a bit deeper look at everything going out over the network.  It gets pretty in depth, but I've found little that matches it.

Comment: How do you determine which process generated the traffic seen in Wireshark?

Answer (score 1):

If you install a firewall that monitors outgoing network traffic - like [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com) it will pop up an alert when a program tries to make a connection.

At that point you can either allow it just that once, allow the application to connect any time or block the application.

The Windows-7 firewall has this functionality built in, but the Windows XP one doesn't (it only monitors inbound traffic). I don't know for certain about the Vista one - but I would guess it doesn't from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Window's built in Resource Monitor to take a look at all the tasks that are accessing your Network interfaces.

Open up your start menu and type in "Resource Monitor" and open it up. There, click on the Network tab and start going through your processes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [firewall log](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753781%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to check application logging for Windows Firewall
The log mentioned above does not show what application generated the log entry, only IP/port information. If auditing for the Windows Filtering Platform is enabled this information can be logged.
Run the following command from an administrative command prompt on the system you would like to enable the [windows filtering platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309058.aspx) logging on:
auditpol /set /subcategory:"{0CCE9225-69AE-11D9-BED3-505054503030}" /failure:enable

Answer (score 1):

TCPview by sysinternals is nice and easy - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

Comment: Very good post, but even more useful program. Thank you.